# Mount.d does not seem to start

Tags: server, mount, nfs

Yesterday my NFS share did work. Today I get:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting
```

On the server, when I restart nfs (service nfs-kernel-server restart) I get:

```
* Stopping NFS kernel daemon                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
* Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                                                                       [ OK ] 
* Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                                                                         [ OK ] 
* Starting NFS kernel daemon                                                                  
Usage: rpc.mountd [-F|--foreground] [-h|--help] [-v|--version] [-d kind|--debug kind]
    [-o num|--descriptors num] [-f exports-file|--exports-file=file]
    [-p|--port port] [-V version|--nfs-version version]
    [-N version|--no-nfs-version version] [-n|--no-tcp]
    [-H ha-callout-prog] [-s|--state-directory-path path]
    [-g|--manage-gids] [-t num|--num-threads=num]
                                                             [fail]
```

This leads me to the conclusion: mount.d does not come up. What do you think? (I tried a lot already, but everything seems fine, except that "Fail" message; I rebooted client and server, reinstalled nfs etc).

In syslog I cant find anything strange, except this:

```
kernel: [  114.548230] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing     export cache
Sep  1 13:43:50 srv262 kernel: [  115.609287] NFSD: Using /var/lib    /nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Sep  1 13:43:50 srv262 kernel: [  115.609299] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net ffffffff81cdab40)
```

What did change in comparison to yesterday? - maybe updates. The machine runs as VM in Vmware Player, maybe Suspend from Vmware did damage some files?

Clients are connected via OpenVPN to the server- as said, it worked until today..

Thx